# Flutter StackTrace error while trying to get Firestore data

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to pull a `bool` value from Firestore, but I've got this error

```
  @patch
  @pragma("vm:external-name", "Error_throwWithStackTrace")
  external static Never _throw(Object error, StackTrace stackTrace);
```

Here's how I tried to get a `bool` T/F value

```
Future<bool> accept = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('usersData')
    .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
    .get()
    .then((value) {
  if (value.data()!['complete'] == true) {
    print('true');
    return Future<bool>.value(true);
  } else if (value.data()!['complete'] == false) {
    print('false');
    return Future<bool>.value(false);
  }
  return false;
});
```

I want to get Boolean T / F and use it in StreamBuilder to check if `value = true` so it can redirect the user to another page

```
class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: ((context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(child: Text('Something went wrong!'));
        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
          if (accept == true) {
            print('true');
            return Dashboard();
          } else {
            print('false');
            return profile();
          }
        } else {
          return AuthPage();
        }
      }),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual error you get?

Comment: Well i already fixed it, but now it returns "false" even when its true in firestore. I've edited post so u can see it

Comment: What returns false? `(value.data() as dynamic)['accept']`?  Are you sure that that value is a `bool` and not, say, a `String`?

Comment: Yes ```(value.data() as dynamic)['accept']``` returns false, and that value is a dynamic, should it be boolean?

Comment: `dynamic` just means that you disable static type checking.  What is the *runtime* type of the value?  That can never be `dynamic`.  If the value's runtime type is not `bool`, then comparing it against `true` will never be true. (Furthermore, comparing `bool`s against `true` or `false` is a code smell since it's never useful.)

Comment: U mean type of value in firestore? There it is a bool. Honestly, I'm new to this, and I don't really understand what you mean ;/

Comment: No, I'm asking what `(value.data() as dynamic)['accept'].runtimeType` returns.

Comment: This is a bool, but it does not return a value to "Future <bool> value" as T / F, but as "Instance of 'Future <bool>'"

Comment: A `Future<bool>` is not a `bool`.  You must `await` a `Future` to extract the value from it.